# XSLT a little confused

Tags: xslt

Having a little trouble with XSLT.. I think I may be going about it completely the wrong way..
Trying to display the customer name with the SKU of items with special 1 status in a line...
then the customer with the special 2 items etc. then part 2(which I haven't started) the items without a status by themselves

so for this XML file the output would be

```
Joe prod1 //special1
Joe prod3 //special2
Joe prod2 //no status
Joe prod4 //no status
Joe prod5 //no status
John Smith prod6 prod8 //special1
John Smith prod7 //no status
John Smith prod9 //no status
John Smith prod10 //no status
```

It kind of works at the moment but the problem is that if there is no special1 or special2 I can't figure out how to make it not print the Customer name..

and I'm not sure how to display the ones with no status afterwards either - any help would be much appreciated!

XML:

```
<customer>
<name>Joe</name>
<order>
    <item>
      <SKU>prod1</SKU>
      <status>special1</status>
    </item>
    <item>
      <SKU>prod2</SKU>
    </item>
    <item>
      <SKU>prod3</SKU>
      <status>special2</status>
    </item>
    <item>
      <SKU>prod4</SKU>
    </item>
    <item>
      <SKU>prod5</SKU>
    </item>
</order>
 </customer>
 <customer
<name>John Smith</name>
<order>
    <item>
      <SKU>prod6</SKU>
      <status>special1</status>
    </item>
    <item>
      <SKU>prod7</SKU>
    </item>
    <item>
      <SKU>prod8</SKU>  
      <status>special1</status>
    </item>
    <item>
     <SKU>prod9</SKU>
</item>
    <item>
      <SKU>prod10</SKU>
    </item>
</order>
```

XSLT:

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet[ <!ENTITY nl "&#xd;&#xa;"> ]>
```

```
<xsl:template match="customer">
    <xsl:value-of select="name" /><xsl:apply-templates select="order/item[status='special1']" /><xsl:text>&nl;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name" /><xsl:apply-templates select="order/item[status='special2']" /><xsl:text>&nl;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[status='special1']"><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="SKU" /></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="item[status=special2']"><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="SKU" /></xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

Comment: If I were you I'd try doing nested `<xsl:for-each>` loops with `<xsl-sort>` elements.

Comment: I've also tried it that way.. doing a for-each through customer.. displaying the Name then a foreach through the special status but I can't figure out how not to display the customer name doing it that way if there's no special status items!

Comment: okay how about I just use an if statement.. sigh been a long day.. I swear I ran into a problem doing it this way before! but so far so good.. thanks for getting me back on track Jacob

Comment: I do not know if you already solved this, but I added a general solution based on Muenchian Grouping. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your simplest option is just an xsl:if

```
<xsl:template match="customer">
    <xsl:if test="order/item[status='special1']">
        <xsl:value-of select="name" /><xsl:apply-templates select="order/item[status='special1']" /><xsl:text>&nl;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="order/item[status='special2']">
        <xsl:value-of select="name" /><xsl:apply-templates select="order/item[status='special2']" /><xsl:text>&nl;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you do not know a priori the set of different status. So, if you wan't your XML to be maintainable (without having to change it each time that you add a different status) you could use the following solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <!-- Use the following key for grouping -->
    <xsl:key name="status-key"
             match="item"
             use="status" />

    <!-- Cache the following operation to avoid doing it several times in the future.
         You can improve performance by changing // to a fixed path in your XML where
         all the items are (e.g. /customers/customer/order/item)  -->
    <xsl:variable name="item-group"
                  select="//item[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('status-key', status)[1])]" />


    <xsl:template match="customer">

        <!-- Obtain the following values before losing the current context -->
        <xsl:variable name="current-id" select="generate-id(.)" />
        <xsl:variable name="current-name" select="name" />

        <!-- Display the products with a status defined -->
        <xsl:for-each select="$item-group">
            <!-- Obtain list of status for this costumer -->
            <xsl:variable name="customer-status"
                          select="key('status-key', status)[generate-id(../..) = $current-id]" />
            <!-- Print the status information if the costumer has at least one status -->
            <xsl:if test="$customer-status">
                <!-- Display the name of the costumer -->
                <xsl:value-of select="$current-name" />
                <!-- Group the product by status -->
                <xsl:for-each select="$customer-status">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', SKU)" />
                </xsl:for-each>
                <!-- Output the status -->
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(' //', status, '&#xa;')" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <!-- Display the prodcuts without status -->
        <xsl:for-each select="order/item[not(status)]">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($current-name, ' ', SKU, ' //no-status&#xa;')" />
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a 'grouping' problem. You are trying to group items by a combination of customer and status. The approach you take to solve this differs by whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0. In XSLT 1.0 you would use a technique called Muenchian Grouping. You start off by defing a key to hold the nodes you are grouping. In this case, you are grouping by **customer** and **item**

```
<xsl:key name="items" match="item" use="concat(generate-id(../..), '|', status)" />
```

Then, for each **customer** element you match, you would get the distinct **status** elements of each **item** like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="order/item
    [status != '']
    [generate-id() = generate-id(key('items', concat(generate-id(../..), '|', status))[1])]" />
```

Essentially what this is doing is looking at each **item** for the customer and selecting the one that occurs first in the key you defined for the status element.

Then, in the template that matches the items with a status, you can then get the individual items with the same status like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('items', concat(generate-id(../..), '|', status))/SKU" />
```

Selecting items with no status though is much easier

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="order/item[not(status != '')]" />
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text"/>
   <xsl:key name="items" match="item" use="concat(generate-id(../..), '|', status)" />

   <xsl:template match="customer">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="order/item[status != ''][generate-id() = generate-id(key('items', concat(generate-id(../..), '|', status))[1])]" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="order/item[not(status != '')]" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="item[status !='']">
      <xsl:value-of select="../../name" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('items', concat(generate-id(../..), '|', status))/SKU" />
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(' //', status, '&#13;')" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="item">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(../../name, ' ', SKU, ' // no status&#13;')" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="SKU">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', .)" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to you XML, the following is output:

```
Joe prod1 //special1
Joe prod3 //special2
Joe prod2 // no status
Joe prod4 // no status
Joe prod5 // no status
John Smith prod6 prod8 //special1
John Smith prod7 // no status
John Smith prod9 // no status
John Smith prod10 // no status
```

If you were using XSLT2.0 it becomes a bit simpler to follow, because you can make us of **xsl:for-each-group** to handle the grouping:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="order/item[status != '']" group-by="status">
```

And then to get the items with the group, you use the **current-group()** function

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/SKU" />
```

Here is the full XSLT2.0 stylesheet which should also output the same results:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:template match="customer">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="order/item[status != '']" group-by="status">
          <xsl:value-of select="../../name" />
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/SKU" />
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(' //', status, '&#13;')" />          
      </xsl:for-each-group>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="order/item[not(status != '')]" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="item">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(../../name, ' ', SKU, ' // no status&#13;')" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="SKU">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', .)" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```